# Freepbx settings storage

Tags: mysql, asterisk, freepbx

Where are freepbx extensions settings are stored? For example, "concurrency limit"

Can't find it in MySQL database. Maybe, this settings are stored in some kind of file storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular setting is stored in the Asterisk database, for easy access from dialplan. You can see it from the Asterisk CLI:

```
database show AMPUSER/1234/concurrency_limit
```

To see all settings that are stored in the Asterisk DB:

```
database show AMPUSER 1234
```

Other settings are in MySQL, try `SELECT * FROM sip WHERE id=1234`, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE extension=1234`, and `SELECT * FROM devices WHERE id=1234`.

Answer (score 1):

Freepbx sip extensions stored in table sip, iax extensions in table iax.

Extension stored in multiple rows.

Except that you have voicemail, which is stored directly into voicemail.conf

Except that you have different settings like followme and DND stored in astdb

Yes, freepbx is not best designed system.